# Jar file execution error

Tags: jar, executable-jar

I wrote a program that runs fine, however packaging the file into a jar file and trying to execute that fails.

The project consists of three files :

```
CinReader.java --> CinReader.class
PageSource.java --> PageSource.class
LocalBot.java --> LocalBot.class (main class)
```

The contents of manifest.txt are :
Main-Class: LocalBot.class

I created the jar file with the command :

```
C:\Users\ioil\Desktop\CSCI20\localBot>jar cvfm LocalBot.jar manifest.txt *.class

added manifest
adding: CinReader.class(in = 5908) (out= 3027)(deflated 48%)
adding: LocalBot.class(in = 362) (out= 272)(deflated 24%)
adding: PageSource.class(in = 5293) (out= 2560)(deflated 51%)

C:\Users\ioil\Desktop\CSCI20\localBot>
```

Now when I enter the command : `"java -jar LocalBot.jar"` or `"LocalBot.jar"` the Java Virtual Machine Launcher returns the error message : `"Could not find the main class: LocalBot. Program will exit"`

Am I doing anything obviously wrong . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Understanding the Manifest](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html)

> When you create a JAR file, it automatically receives a default
>   manifest file. There can be only one
>   manifest file in an archive, and it
>   always has the pathname
>   
> `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`